# Decidability of language L = { n : ∃x∈N, n = 3x+2 }

Tags: computability

I've recently came across this language and I don't know if my hint for proving its class is correct or not.

$$L = \{ n : \exists x \in N, \,n=3x+2 \} $$$n$ is in binary format.

I think $L$ is decidable and as proof I was considering using a canonical enumerator of $\{0,1\}^*$.

For each word $x$ printed by the enumerator, my algorithm would compute $3x+2$ and halt if the result was equal or greater to the provided input.
If equal, then accept, if greater, then reject.

I would like someone to confirm if I'm correct, pointing me in the right direction if I'm not.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: I think your solution is OK, as long as your starting enumerator does the right thing: it's important that number $x$ is not tried until all numbers $<x$ have been tried. Otherwise, you may get wrong rejections.

Comment: I think the language is regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct.

The description of your algorithm would be clearer if it also mentions the following.

- The algorithm rejects the empty word immediately.
- That canonical enumerator of $\{0,1\}^∗$ enumerates all positive integers in increasing order.
- If $3x+2$ is smaller than the input then the result will be ignored and the enumerator will keep going.

Another algorithm that decides the language would be subtracting 3 from the input number and checking the result repeatedly. If the result is 2, it accepts. If the result is negative, it rejects. It also rejects the the empty word immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understood the "accepted for good" and "rejected for good" parts. But, isn't the point of an algorithm to always halt, accepting/rejecting accordingly? I don't see the problem with the specification I gave :(

Comment: Well, I didn't specify that if _3x+2 < input_ then the result would be ignored and the simulation of the enumerator would keep going, but once done that then yes, it works. It rejects 1 with x=0, accepts 2 with x=0 and rejects 3 with x=1. Also, if the input is the empty word, then reject immediately. If I convert the binary representation of the input to unary then all I need to do to check equivalence with 3x+2 is to compare each digit, so I can effectively compare both numbers and procede the algorithm accordingly to the result.

Comment: Thats no problem, I actually thought of the skipping rule after describing the algorithm but I decided not  to include it. Anyway, I agree that is important for correctness, thanks! Also, thanks for that second approach, its really simple, nice.

Comment: I just deleted all my comments since they become outdated by the updated answer.